# Recommend an efficient data structure for storing large repeating values in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I have 20 labels (say 1 to 20) which are repeated many times randomly to create a list with million numbers. At any given time, given a label, I need a random index from that list containing that label.

It is important that when the same label is queried repeatedly, the probability of same index returned is minimum.

I have tried using dict with key as the label and value as the list of indices and then during querying, used random.choice() to get one of the indices. But the process of creating a grouping (with dict) is too slow.

Please suggest a better and faster way to create a grouping of such kind.

Comment: It seems like you solution is not the best. If you need to do weighted random choice, you can use [`random.choices()`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/random.html#random.choices) with `weights` argument.

Comment: How is it too slow? Should be O(1)

Comment: Does any list change in size after creation? Also the phrase `It is important that when the same label is queried repeatedly, the probability of same index returned is minimum` is unclear: do you just want big lists (so that each index's chance of being selected is low) or do you actually want to lower a given index's probability after it has been selected the first time?

Comment: please show your slow code.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @juvian. I meant the process of creating a dict with key as the label and and list of indices as value is slow. Is there any better way to create a grouping?

Comment: @Chillie By that line, I meant we need to use some kind of `random.choice` and not have a single index for every label and return it everytime.

Comment: @Ajay thats probably because python is slow, algorithm should be fine. How long is it taking? How long does it take just to iterate over all numbers without processing anything?

Comment: @juvian For tens of million values in list, the dict process is taking 3 seconds while the constructing the same using list of lists takes 2.5 secs. Anything better than 2.5secs? And any idea why dict is slower?

Comment: @Ajay why wouldn´t it be? dicts support more than list as keys, thus [they are doing more work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21200525/3308055).

Comment: "Please suggest a better and faster way to create a grouping of such kind." -> There isn´t. Would need further context to know why you need that and why you have the data in that format to begin with

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward approach would be to invert your mapping. So instead of having a list `L` of a million numbers, each one between 1 and 20, you have a dict of 20 lists, each of those containing the *indices* of `L` which are equal to a particular label. You can construct that dictionary of lists of indices from `L`, or you can even construct it randomly without constructing `L`. Watch:

```py
import random

NUM_LABELS = 20
NUM_ENTRIES = 1000000

labels = list(range(1, NUM_LABELS+1))

# L is constructed
L = []
for _ in range(NUM_ENTRIES):
    L.append(random.choice(labels))

# D is constructed
D = {label:[] for label in labels}
for i, label in enumerate(L):
    D[label].append(i)

# finding a random index containing label 3
idx = random.choice(D[3])
print("index {} has label {}".format(idx, L[idx]))

# Building D without building L
del D,L

D = {label:[] for label in labels}
for i in range(NUM_ENTRIES):
    D[random.choice(labels)].append(i)

idx = random.choice(D[3])
print("index {} has label 3, take my word for it!".format(idx))
```

Comment: constructing this dict (D) is slower than constructing a list of lists (where list[1] is a list of indices with label 1) for larger size of lists.

Comment: @Ajay there's nothing in your problem description that specifies the labels will always be numeric and sequential.  It's not unreasonable to assume that labels may be names.  This is one of the reasons you need to show your code - doing so exposes some of your implicit assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

If (1) you have some guarantee on the distribution of labels and (2) you only need a small part of the indexes, you could try the following lazy method:

- generate a long random list `L` of indices without repetition (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister);
- create an empty cache `label -> list of some indices` (a `dict` of `list`s or a `list` of `list`s);
- for a given label `label`:

  - if there are indices in the cache, yield them
  - else take the next index of `L` and do one of the following: (a) yield the index if the value is the expected label or else (b) store the index in the cache and repeat with the next index.

This *may or may not* be faster than the naive (but usually efficient) method, depending one the use case and the data.

Proof of concept:

```
import random

class IndicesGenerator:
    def __init__(self, labels, huge_list, next_idx):
        self._cache = {x:[] for x in labels}
        self._huge_list = huge_list
        self._next_idx = next_idx

    def find(self, label, N=100):
        indices = self._cache[label]
        k = 0
        while indices and k<N: # while there are stored indices and we need indices
            yield indices.pop() # yield indices
            k += 1
        while k<N: # need for more indices
            i = self._next_idx()
            v = self._huge_list[i]
            if v == label: # hit!
                k += 1
                yield i
            else: # cache the values for next search
                self._cache[v].append(i)

labels = list(range(20))
SIZE = 20000
huge_list = random.choices(labels, k=SIZE)
gen = IndicesGenerator(labels, huge_list, lambda: random.randint(0, SIZE-1))

# helper function: pPrint a chunk of the list around index i
def print_context(i):
    return "[{}, {}, {}]".format(
        "..., "+str(huge_list[i-1]) if i>0 else "...",
        huge_list[i],
        str(huge_list[i+1])+", ..." if i<SIZE-1 else "..."
    )

needle = random.choice(range(20))
print("search for", needle)
print("cache before search", gen._cache)
print(", ".join([f"{i}->{print_context(i)}" for i in gen.find(needle, 10)]))
print("cache after search", gen._cache)
```

As you see, the cache is ready to provide most of the indices of other labels without any computation.

Average case time complexity:

- the initialization or the refill of the cache is `O(k*|labels|)` where `k` is the number of indices to provide for the first label
- the search for any other label is `O(k)` in best case; real average case complexity requires a more subtle computation, but should be around this value.

Obviously, the space complexity is `O(k*|labels|)` too (size of the cache in average case).

In the worst case, you (almost) build all complete lists as is the naive method, but with the overhead of the random number generator. (Time and space complexity are the same as the naive method.)